# Excel - I get an error when I try to add a column

Tags: asp.net, excel

We get an excel worksheet from a customer and there is a data discrepancy with one of the col. the item description they send. We want to programmatically open the document lookup the table using item column, and then write a new column with the item description from the table (on SQLSever) that part of getting the data is fine but how to create such a new column is where I am stumped. writing in asp.net but open to however it can be done

I am getting this error when trying to insert a column:

> To prevent possible loss of data, Excel cannot shift nonblank cells
>   off of the worksheet. Select another location in which to insert new
>   cells, or delete data from the end of your worksheet.
>
> If you do not have data in cells that can be shifted off of the
>   worksheet, you can reset which cells Excel considers nonblank. To do
>   this, press <kbd>CTRL+End</kbd> to locate the last nonblank cell on the
>   worksheet. Delete this cell and all cells between it and the last row
>   and column of your data then save.

Comment: not sure if this is it. seems to be a known problem, i am instead writing a new sheet, copying the one i am interested in and adding there a column no problem. this works for us so the problem is closed but would be interested to know if you can add a column programatically to an exisiting sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not linked to your code, it happens when you **have data on the last column** (and so Excel do not want you to loose it).

Yet, the trick is Excel considers that **any style is the same as data**. So, if you have ever **defined a style on the whole row**, inserting a column may cause this error.

Let me give an **example** to explain it more:

1. Create a new Excel workbook
2. Select the whole first row
3. Paint it in Yellow (or whatever color)
4. Select cells from A1 to E1
5. Paint them in white
6. Try to insert a new column before B
7. You get the error because Excel does consider that you wanted to define a specific style to the last cell so you would loose this information if you inserted a new column

Have a look at your file to solve this issue (IMHO, defining style on a whole row is a bad practice because it could cause this kind of error).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I often get this annoying bug bothering me.

To avoid this behavior in *Excel 2007*, what you do is you go to the end of your data with <kbd>CTRL+end</kbd>.

Then you go one cell down (or one cell right if you are at the bottom), and **copy this cell** ( <kbd>CTRL+c</kbd>), that *should be blank*, since your outside your data.

Then go back to the place where *you* (not that stupid Excel) consider your data should stop, while holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, and paste it (<kbd>CTRL+v</kbd>).

After this you should be able to insert that column.